# How to append data from JSON file to HTML div?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am attempting to loop through the JSON file and append each instance of "sliderLink" to a preexisting DIV, however it appears it is not working.

I am getting the following error code in the console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.coopertimewell.com/mainSlider.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How do I fix this? 
But this seems to be working in [**jsbin**](https://jsbin.com/ruxunolada/edit?html,js,output)

```
<div class="custom-container">
</div>

<script>
    //populate timeline select menu
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.coopertimewell.com/mainSlider.json',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            crossorigin: true,
            success: fillInFields
        });
    });

    function fillInFields(data) {
        var pictureURLArray = [];
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            pictureURLArray.push(value.sliderLink);
        });
        var lengthDatabase = Object.keys(data).length;
        for (i = 0; i < lengthDatabase; i++) {
            $(".custom-container").append(pictureURLArray[i]);
        }
    };

</script>
```

Comment: Seems to be working, what is the problem?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @Justcode would you be able to show me your output? I am just getting a blank page.

Comment: @adiga no I don't

Comment: @adiga https://jsbin.com/ruxunolada/edit?html,js,output check this

Comment: @Justcode for some reason I am not getting any output at all

Comment: @CoopDaddio can you try to reproduce it in that link?

Comment: In the jsbin link you have shared, it's working fine. I'm able to see the links. Or do you want those images to be displayed instead of the links, inside your `div`?

Comment: No I am just after the links @adiga.

Comment: @Justcode when I copy and paste the HTML exactly into your link I get an error:
    "error"
    "@https://null.jsbin.com/runner:16:5
    l</b.render/<@https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.7.min.js:1:13922
    k</a.use/<@https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.7.min.js:1:10866
    "

Comment: @CoopDaddio you need to reproduce it

Comment: @adiga I was in fact getting an error in the console

Comment: @holydragon I have edited question

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568923/cors-error-with-ajax-request).

Comment: @holydragon changed to jsonp, and error did go away, but still no output.

Comment: Then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header).

Answer (score 0):

You should check console of this request (F12 and choose Console tab)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.coopertimewell.com/mainSlider.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    crossorigin: true,
    success: fillInFields
});
```

if have error like as: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.coopertimewell.com/mainSlider.json' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

You should install `Moesif Origin & CORS Changer` extension for Chrome and setting like as below:

[[image]]

After that turn on this extension and try it.

Comment: I have just checked, and yes I am in fact getting this error. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: I don't know about that. But you can research by here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522749/how-to-solve-redirect-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow

Comment: This only "solves" the problem on your own machine, you will encouter the same on other machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about how to support CORS. You should read the questions like this:[Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Anyway, the simpliest fix for you is to change `dataType: "json" to "jsonp".`

Comment: I have tried to change the dataType from json to jsonp, and although this does remove the error I am still getting a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the actual URL was causing the issue.

Only change that I had to make:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'mainSlider.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    crossorigin: true,
    success: fillInFields
  });
});
```