# My GET request works fine in POSTMAN but not in JavaScript code

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I make my get request with POSTMAN, it works just fine and I get the expected response. I just set type to GET, insert my URL and insert a key named token and set it to a token I get from another service.
but when I try to call the same service in code like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    headers: {"token": myToken},
    url: myURL,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

or this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    beforeSend: function(xhr, setting){xhr.setRequestHeader('token', myToken);},
    url: myURL,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I get 401 error.
I also found out that the server is not receiving the token in the request header. Any ideas how I can fix this? Cheers.

=====================================================

UPDATE:
POSTMAN generated code which fails as well:

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://test.mirasnafis.ir/marketer/rating",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6IjEwY2U5NTUxLWExNTItNDc2ZC05ZTA0LTIyOGMyOGUwMmEwYSIsIm5iZiI6MTU2NTE1NDU0NywiZXhwIjoxNTk2Nzc2OTQ3LCJpYXQiOjE1NjUxNTQ1NDcsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAxOTEiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjUwMTkxIn0.YhdwgSW1NzHavdtXTMlHOvbOmgjlUXk81PKGg4v0cXc",
    "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "c7e92763-dc2e-4db8-a442-c5b8275e7bf5,d6fa9ad9-29e2-482e-9c46-de89f9a42c3b",
    "Host": "test.mirasnafis.ir",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

and

```
var data = null;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://test.mirasnafis.ir/marketer/rating");
xhr.setRequestHeader("token", "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6IjEwY2U5NTUxLWExNTItNDc2ZC05ZTA0LTIyOGMyOGUwMmEwYSIsIm5iZiI6MTU2NTE1NDU0NywiZXhwIjoxNTk2Nzc2OTQ3LCJpYXQiOjE1NjUxNTQ1NDcsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAxOTEiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjUwMTkxIn0.YhdwgSW1NzHavdtXTMlHOvbOmgjlUXk81PKGg4v0cXc");
xhr.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Postman-Token", "c7e92763-dc2e-4db8-a442-c5b8275e7bf5,8da9d6a1-0670-41f5-8049-3b96a28b0e3f");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Host", "test.mirasnafis.ir");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: depends upon how your server accepts token. mostly its accepts in Authorization Header. how you did it in postman?

Comment: Can you please show how you have set this in postman? Also, can you try making the request using curl or wget? That will help you to figure out why it is not working in your AJAX call.

Comment: @RV in the 3rd tab which is titled Headers, set a `KEY` to token and its VALUE to the string I get from another service.

Comment: are you getting some else errors like CORS..?

Comment: @ArashChM maybe it can help, but postman can generate code for you with a working get or post call. So after you ran the code, You can find a button to the right called `code` (just below your send button) and here you can select `javascript` from the dropdown

Comment: @RV yes im getting that error after the 401

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568923/cors-error-with-ajax-request.
or 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header
 this might help you.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I didn't know that feature existed. however i ran both XHR and jquery codes provided by postman, first I got 4 new errors saying `refused to add unsafe header` for user agent and 3 others. I also got the former errors as well. After removing them, I still get the errors I started with. I will update the post with postman code.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258645/pass-request-headers-in-a-jquery-ajax-get-call

Comment: @RV the jsonp solution removed the CORS error but I still get the 401

Comment: didnt get mean by jsonp!!

Comment: try passing header like this.
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Custom " + btoa("token:" + yourToken));
},

Answer (score 2):

Please check this is work!!!

Always token accepted in JSON format so need to pass in `'Accept': 'application/json'` OR `'Contact-type': 'application/json'`.

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   headers: {
      'token': Token,
      'Accept': 'application/json',
   },
   url: YOURURL,
   cache: false,
   success: function(result) {
       console.log(result);
   }
});
```

Comment: If do you get **401 Unauthorized** Error.
It is passing wrong token issue **please verified you're token first**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
            url: URL,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'header1': 'value1',
                'header2': 'value2'
            },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {
               // CallBack(result);
            },
            error: function (error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Dinesh you should always leave a comment to your answer about why this solution works, posting only code, is not always helpful