# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin ': '*' is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I tried to answer all the questions related to this tag but I was not successful where is my mistake?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin ': '*'
        },
        success: function (xml) {
            alert("Success");

        }

    });
});
```

My error;

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml' from origin 'http://localhost:44318' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I'm using jquery ajax in asp.net framework.please I tried the answers to all questions please do not throw the question title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS error with ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568923/cors-error-with-ajax-request)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200742/discussion-on-question-by-enes-ozturk-access-control-allow-origin-is-not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml",
    dataType: "xml",

    success: function(xml) {
      console.log('success')
      var xmlText = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml);
      var xmlTextNode = document.createTextNode(xmlText);
      var parentDiv = document.getElementById('xml');
      parentDiv.appendChild(xmlTextNode);
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="xml"></div>
```

Comment: waow. my problem is solved endless thanks but I would like to know why would you give information such a url did you give

Comment: Sorry - didn't really get your question. Why would I do what?

Comment: why did you give such a url ?

Comment: You mean why does this URL work? Please, read the **npm** documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere. **Heroku** is a cloud provider, and **herokuapp.com** is the base URL of their cloud solution. So, **cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com** is a service, that parses the URL you pass it, and returns the resource you query. With the **npm documentation** you can do your own service like that (it's free :) )